# New Belarusian ruble isn't supported by java.util.currency

Tags: java, currency

Why isn't the currency New Belarusian ruble (BYN) with nummeric code 933 supported by java.util.Currency? If I check ISO 4217 it's there, but the code isn't available in the Currency class (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217).

```
        for (Currency currency : Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()) {   
            allCurrenciesMap.put(currency.getNumericCode(), currency.getCurrencyCode());
        }

        SortedSet<Integer> sortedNumericKeysMap = new TreeSet<>(allCurrenciesMap.keySet());
        for (Integer numericCurrencyCode : sortedNumericKeysMap) { 
           String currencyCode = allCurrenciesMap.get(numericCurrencyCode);
           System.out.println("Currency: " + currencyCode + ", nummeric: " + numericCurrencyCode);
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: If not, it sounds like a bug you may want to report to have it fixed.

Comment: Bug report created -> http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8171296